# roslaunch dies with exit code -11 after it stops receiving topic from bag file

Tags: roslaunch, roscpp, ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The node behaves as expected while it receives a topic but as soon as the topic playback terminates, an error is thrown and the launch file (node) stops. I also can't find the log file in the mentioned location.

```
[visualize_ros-1] process has died [pid 23305, exit code -11, cmd /home/sverma/catkin_ws/devel/lib/quanergy/visualize_ros __name:=visualize_ros __log:=/home/sverma/.ros/log/3d1f5648-afc8-11ea-9ecb-d07e35604451/visualize_ros-1.log].
log file: /home/sverma/.ros/log/3d1f5648-afc8-11ea-9ecb-d07e35604451/visualize_ros-1*.log
all processes on machine have died, roslaunch will exit
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/355158/roslaunch-dies-with-exit-code--11-after-it-stops-receiving-topic-from-bag-file/) by [surabhi96](https://answers.ros.org/users/32900/surabhi96/) on ROS Answers with karma: 41 on 2020-06-17

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [fergs](https://answers.ros.org/users/84/fergs/) on 2020-06-18**:
I'd suggest posting the actual launch file contents - otherwise this is somewhat impossible to debug

**Comment by [Solrac3589](https://answers.ros.org/users/31684/solrac3589/) on 2020-06-18**:
As @fergs says, We need more information in order to try to guess what's happening. Maybe at least explaining which data gives the bag file?

**Comment by [surabhi96](https://answers.ros.org/users/32900/surabhi96/) on 2020-06-18**:
@fergs @Solrac3589

```
<launch>

    <arg name="path"/>

    <node pkg="my_pkg" type="my_node" name="my_node" output="screen">
        <param name="path" value="$(arg path)" />
    </node> 

</launch>
```

**Comment by [surabhi96](https://answers.ros.org/users/32900/surabhi96/) on 2020-06-18**:
Also, I managed to get the most recent log file (although it was not the same name as mentioned in the console) and it says: `error: [Errno 111] Connection refused`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I think the error is just a node trying to connect to a service that is already shut down. Are you running the bag and the node in different machines/networks. Have you properly set up the `ROS_MASTER_URI`/`ROS_IP` enviromental variables. Check [this](http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/EnvironmentVariables).

Besides that, exit code -11 means a `SIGSEGV` that basically means a segmentation fault, maybe in your code you have something that is crashing the excution. Just to be sure you can debug it GDB.

---

Originally posted by [Weasfas](https://answers.ros.org/users/34184/weasfas/) with karma: 1695 on 2020-06-18

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0